# How to define generic types for each object in an array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a form in react. The form has inputs with different data types. It can be `string` or `number`, or array of types, basically unknown. The user has to define it.

With a single Input it's straightforward: [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAsAFD8YATzBUACozCEAPABUAfHAC8ufnDjAAdsBgA1FABt8SAFxxZmNXDCM0SQoTMAKAG6HjZ2QEpli2f2p%20fiQAD0hYODQITUJ4AElNMHx4FTlMeSccKy0dfSMkSz51Gwg7B0LqMwkIKTl5LzNkdBgAOiaMAFEDJBAkTRTFLKLI6Ni4AG03fOxiPXckAF1lAmIyCiQ6pxy5-K9eAWH2GHwoTTgnK3VpLSSYS-U4KeMlHCeqFEICTQBrTQgAdzOHzgsSgWgA5oFhg84NEAMIACxQmnBSBemTg5CgqJgZjwbzMABNgLAhHljDQaD4lIN7jCojF4CUysRCeSqCpmfZCE5iaT2XBgfgfn9AYLPt59nSHrN2U4uQ4kGz5ntpdQoTCAPTyKyqvjUKV8JzUxQXYaazX0FDAAyfABGSDQKCIVDeGk%20mnwIAdUGwyMJGk0hNCAHk6HBCRB7JoWPBQsAxtE4J7vUgoFZpAlboHcvMXgAWWgKwgvN00uAAAwAJK95i0tMGQmGnCx8ywvNQK7Rtfw9fxjb5zlYLVabfbHc7iJiEVQjiczsJRLDw8X3cmvT7sH94KCIRms8kcztnjhWywi7ZuaX5oO3vWg6G6C22x24D2%20H2jSah%20bLWAPsQ45Oi6jw3gmIIwGCKLYA2j5wPGsSfEmu7QYKQbWJeDhwHOpyfCh4L7okh7bOyLxnhepRXrW%20SDtW1HGPejbNmeHZdm%20OoflwQA).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type Props<T> = {
  initValue: T,
  process: (value: T) => T
}

export const Input = <T,>({
  initValue,
  process,
}: Props<T>): React.ReactElement => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initValue);

  return (
    <input
      value={value as unknown as string}
      onChange={({ target: { value: dirtyValue } }) => {
        const processedValue = process(dirtyValue as unknown as T);

        setValue(processedValue);
      }}
    />
  );
};

() => (
  // fails because value is number, and indexOf doesn't exist on number
  <Input initValue={4} process={value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`} />
);

() => (
  // fails because the return type of process is number, not string
  <Input initValue={'4'} process={value => value.indexOf('4')} />
);

() => (
  // passes because value is string, indexOf exists on string, and process returns string
  <Input initValue={'4'} process={value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`} />
);
```

The above code doesn't really make sense, it just explains what I would like to reach. I want to raise this behaviour to the next level, so the inputs are controlled centrally by a form component, and the inputs are passed to its props like:

```
<Form
  inputs={[
    {
      id: 'string',
      initValue: '4', // `initValue` type is string, so `process` will get string as well, and must return string
      process: value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`,
    },
    {
      id: 'number',
      initValue: 4, // `initValue` type is number, so `process` will get number as well, and must return number
      process: value => value + 2,
    },
    {
      id: 'array',
      initValue: [0, 1, 2], // `initValue` type is array of numbers, so `process` will get array of numbers as well, and must return array of numbers
      process: values => values.filter(Boolean),
    },
  ]}
  onSubmit={({ string, number, array }) => {
    // inside the component the array of objects are reduced to a single object, where key is `id`,
    // value is value corresponding to it, matching the type defined in `initValue`
    console.log(
      typeof string === 'string' &&
      typeof number === 'number' &&
      Array.isArray(array)
    ); //ideally logs true
  }}
/>
```

I was playing around, and trying out different things to reach what I want, but the issue with my try is I can only define one type generic for an array. So wrapping the `Input` component's typing logic with an array, I have to specify the type generic. So if I try to have:

```
type InputProps<T> = {
  id: string;
  initValue: T;
  process: (value: T) => T;
};

type InputList = InputProps[]; // Generic type 'InputProps' requires 1 type argument(s)

type Props<Inputs extends InputList> = {
  inputs: Inputs;

  onSubmit: (values: InputList) => unknown;
};
```

Basically I could have an array of input props, but with only one type for all. I want each object to have its own type in the array, so I can have the same behaviour when defining the `Form` component's `inputs` prop, as the `Input` component's props.

In the `Form`, instead of me manually specifying the `Input`s, I want to have this component that collects, and controls them in one place. Obviously inside `Form` component it will be a black box, but I want to be able to match the types from the outside when I use it. So `process` function (just as in the example of `Input` above) knows that it will receive its `value` parameter with the same type as `initValue`, but also I want to construct an object with the keys of each object's `id` in the `inputs` array, and the value must match the type of the object's `initValue`.

Is this possible based on the above?

**EDIT**

I was able to produce something that seemed working in the beginning, but then realised some weird things are going on [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4BJAOzAFcYAFHMAZwA8AFThIAHjCQsAJn2ZtOAGWB8YwgHwAaOAGlREqbLgBrJLQiY4Q9XAC8cAN5U4cYC2AwAaigA27JABcVgDaOgC6wfhuHt5%20SPhhFJQuYDhoSHx8QQAUAG6%20-kFCoRFR7l4F8WEAlHY2xeGR0RVxCUkAvkk09IysHDDKqsL6kjJyfUoqatY29k7JcKGuLCZmFlZhQRPcvIJC2jrqVJ1U3Qxwsf57I4bjCgNTGrOOzot6bqvmlkKbIY1lMUqCWOp0odHOPAg-GG4lGRm2g2m6me8xcbn6WSsXQWEBYAGV2AAjEAeHL5OKYy4ZDS1Ww2dgsYwsCAAdxYHWx4kgsDgaFxqjgADFoHh7DCDGN5P1ERpNOpsqjlhjtLiCcSPMcgpDodZaTZsq8BNJgLl1AIAPTG01UarY7J6uAGhYCYVQECvNH3Pi2ByKlwuVRQNwAcyCfv9nsBcSC%20AALPhtObzXAAAbNKkpuDgxgqOCBkPaPgQVOpCDpTKZlnAHw%20ODBpDwfMsYNwFByFlIGvaFAyOAgdgCogwdhQFZN4MeiNwUvlzHk-x1VMAEgc86QADo3NJxAB5TDZOP4artFOaScudpnhYRljsECEpBQMPn-3pypBWOJ5Np8oZrM9Vw5Fve9H0LYsUxnDI%20Erata3reBgIfKBW3bTsfG7Xt%200HBsRxWRDHxfFI0igoI10XMiAGo4AAJivKc4EvF8UCgKAUFoZ9rynN9o0WAAGbQAEZtGosIv1Tbj-EzbNANbFi2LgdZ8KgPgwJLYiKzgKsazrBtZNY2gFMsJS5DbTS0Iw6Q%20wHeAh1wvT5MUu8kL4Qjp3UudKjkOk4DXPh10watJCgbIACEIAgHxUBYao6KnRjOPadpJyTBT8SJEkYB9BU8xgINm20JTuzkgz2gdcMUpcFK3D4YBtyzAALRg%20XAXEpHgGBGvsgz1ggQkACskAwEyiDgIhpHYdJLJgYsUDzENIoU-rBpgbQWUakbTAM3M02kU9kuTSrkzI3MyL5FiMkgGQQyzYsPG0EAUBgNB6uujrGGk7cApYJBLI%20H8o0k-b-T5Fgi0i9cfAgYMnQjCr-WzdZxzsWx7Hwcd8DgAAyTGgYjBGjKcx9kdRpSMex3H-QAQWKzc%20Gp-TsmY-Tqgp204CTWrUBrAzIeDORcv8IHEtec0jkoaogA).

It looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

type InputProps<T extends InputList<T>, K extends keyof T> = {
  initValue: T[K]['initValue'];
  process: (value: T[K]['initValue']) => T[K]['initValue'];
};

type InputList<T extends InputList<T>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: InputProps<T, K>
};

type Values<T extends InputList<T>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]['initValue']
}

type Props<T extends InputList<T>> = {
  inputs: T;

  onSubmit: (values: Values<T>) => unknown;
};

export const Form = <T extends InputList<T>,>({
  inputs, onSubmit
}: Props<T>) => (
  <div></div>
);

() => (
  <Form
    inputs={{
      string: {
        initValue: '4', // `initValue` type is string, so `process` will get string as well, and must return string
        process: value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`,
      },
      number: {
        initValue: 4, // `initValue` type is number, so `process` will get number as well, and must return number
        process: value => value + 2,
      },
      array: {
        initValue: [0, 1, 2], // `initValue` type is array of numbers, so `process` will get array of numbers as well, and must return array of numbers
        process: values => values.filter(Boolean),
      },
    }}
    // onSubmit={({ string, number, array }) => {
    //   // inside the component the array of objects are reduced to a single object, where key is `id`,
    //   // value is value corresponding to it, matching the type defined in `initValue`
    //   console.log(
    //     typeof string === 'string' &&
    //     typeof number === 'number' &&
    //     Array.isArray(array)
    //   ); //ideally logs true
    // }}
  />
);
```

If you type the `process` function, it gives a peek about what the function's type should be, but once written, it shows the value as `unknown`. Also, once `onSubmit` is defined, everything is messed up, and it's not even sure about the key types, so something's still wrong.

Comment: I dont think I understood the question. Could you please tell me which part of the code do you want to fix?

Comment: Please let me know if this is what you want to achieve https://catchts.com/callbacks#callback_in_union%202 ?

Comment: Actually it helped a lot to develop an extremely ugly, but working solution, so thanks a lot. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Why it is extremely ugly solution? This is a small utility helper

Comment: See my update on the bottom. It's inspired by the link you sent.

Comment: ry to use helper function for building `{ initValue, process }` object

Comment: Are  `string`, `number`,`array` required? Or it can be `foo`, `bar`, `baz` ?

Comment: It can be any key

Comment: Are you allowed to use extra helper for building { initValue, process } object ?